# How to add cksum in find command

Tags: linux, find, checksum

```
$ cksum sample.txt
2763733609 1659 sample.txt

$ find /usr/local/sqoop -printf '%i,%b,%M,%n,%u,%g,%s,%Tc,%h/%f'$'\n'
19404466,8,-rwxr-xr-x,1,hduser,hduser,1345,Monday 27 April 2015 12:12:36 PM IST,/usr/local/sqoop/conf/sqoop-env-template.sh
```

After file name I have to display `cksum` of the file in the above `find` command.
How to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Abu

Answer (score 1):

**`find`** + **`cksum`** solution:

```
find /usr/local/sqoop -type f -printf '%i,%b,%M,%n,%u,%g,%s,%Tc,%h/%f,' \
-exec sh -c 'cksum {} | cut -d" " -f1' \;
```

Comment: @Fazil, what do you mean? You've specified a concrete path `/usr/local/sqoop` - why do you ask about "parent directory" now?

Comment: How to make comma seperated data for cksum

find hadoop-3.0.0 -type f | xargs cksum

2840095922 951 hadoop-3.0.0/etc/hadoop/mapred-env.cmd

I have to make the result set as comma seperated like below
2840095922,951,hadoop-3.0.0/etc/hadoop/mapred-env.cmd

How to do it
Thanks in advance.